# 'Error in model.frame.default ,variable lengths differ' when trying to run the code in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn

I was trying a ML algorithm and for that i used `Heights` data from `dslabs` library.
I want to find F1 values for different values of k in KNN algorithm. 
Firstly i created test and train sets withe `set.seed()` as required.
Then defined F1 using `sapply`. But I am getting the error as shown:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ ., data = train_set) : 
>      variable lengths differ (found for 'sex')

the code is given below.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(dslabs)
data("heights")

# define the outcome and predictors
set.seed(1,sample.kind = "Rounding")
y <- heights$sex
x <- heights$height

# generate training and test sets
test_index <- createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
test_set <- heights[test_index, ]
train_set <- heights[-test_index, ]
length(test_set$sex)
length(train_set$sex)

# defining F1 
k_value<-seq(1,101,3)
F_1 <- sapply(k_value,function(k){
  knn_fit<- knn3(y~.,data = train_set, k=k) %>% factor(levels = levels(train_set$sex))
  y_hat_knn<- predict(knn_fit,test_set,type='class')
  F_meas(data = y_hat_knn,reference = factor(train_set$sex))
})
```

Can anyone tell me what is the mistake ? Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is your definition of your data.

#### The Problem

First you define

```r
y <- heights$sex
x <- heights$height
```

but you don't use them later on. Well, you use `y`, but not in the right way.

Then you define your test and train datasets:

```r
test_index <- createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
test_set   <- heights[test_index, ]
train_set  <- heights[-test_index, ]
```

At this point a hint: `p=0.5` i.e. taking 50 % of your data for training and 50 % for testing is uncommon (for me). Better use something about `p = 0.75`.

For the sake of simplification, I just take the `knn3`-part out of your `sapply`-function:

```r
knn_fit <- knn3(y~., data = train_set, k=k)
```

Here's your mistake. You set `data = train_set`. Let's take a look at the structure of `train_set`:

```r
> head(train_set)
      sex height
2    Male     70
3    Male     68
5    Male     61
6  Female     65
9  Female     66
```

Now your formula is given by `y~.`, but `train_set` simply doesn't have a `y` component.

#### The Solution

Change your function to

```r
knn_fit <- knn3(sex ~., data = train_set, k=k)
```

to get your desired result. In this case remove `x` and `y` from your script since they aren't used.

#### An Annotation

Your dummy-function used by `sapply` doesn't return anything. Perhaps that's another issue that will occure.